# Google Collab network error while launching new notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

Am getting the below network error while launching new notebook in Google Collab

Error
**Unable to load Collaboratory.**

A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
GapiError: A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
    at mI.Du [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:671:118)
    at new mI (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:1387:170)
    at Ba.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:1482:22)
    at Ea (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:17:336)
    at Ba.throw_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:16:402)
    at Ga.throw (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:18:248)
    at c (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200515-085600-RC01_311774571:25:304)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by removing the Colab Notebooks folder that is shared with me.
(I had two Colab Notebooks directory in my Google Drive. One that I used to use and others shared with me.)

Long story to short, I think the specified parent in error message points implicitly(sadly not explicitly) Colab Notebooks.

https://support.google.com/drive/thread/12526192?msgid=14922479